# How to detect memory of a Web page on Android?

Tags: browser, ram

I want to test the memory of a Web page on Android. The memory is mainly used for DOM, so I need to know the overall memory, rather than JavaScript memory.

Any idea?

Comment: Which browser? The memory use and the technique will be different from one browser to another?

Comment: @DanHulme Native browser of Android.

Comment: That depends on the Android version and manufacturer. Recent Android versions use Chrome as the native browser, but some manufacturers still include their own browser. Please [edit] your question to add these details.